# Dynamically adjust y-min/max after range-selector in Dygraph

Tags: dygraphs

When the range selector is used to shrink/expand the viewing x-range, the y axis remains unchanged. Is there a way to update these values based on the current min/max?

I know there is a way to update the settings, the problem is I don't know how to capture the current min/max on the range selector. What I have set up is a function that gets called on the draw() callback so the only thing I'm missing is how to calculate the current range min/max values.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to call the [`yAxisRange`](http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#yAxisRange) method:

> `yAxisRange(idx)`
>
> Returns the currently-visible y-range for an axis. This can be affected by zooming, panning or a call to updateOptions. Axis indices are zero-based. If called with no arguments, returns the range of the first axis. Returns a two-element array: [bottom, top].

Comment: Right except that range doesn't change if you set the ymin and ymax values. I set these min max values so when the user zooms using the range selector, the min max values don't get updated so yAxisRange() always returns the ymin ymax originally set

Comment: In that case you'll need to scan across the data yourself using `getValue`. You can get the x-values from the zero-th column.